# Using SASS source maps with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

Whenever I get an error for sass in my terminal, it always says the style.scss outputs the errors.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{}!./~/sass-loader?{}!./src/scss/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/sketch-arrow-2.png' in 'C:\www\webpack\src\scss'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{}!./~/sass-loader?{}!./src/scss/style.scss 6:77832-77870
 @ ./src/scss/style.scss
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/app.js
```

However, that style is actually in a SASS partial. It doesn't say which file.

I tried using source maps with sass-loader but it just outputs a similar error.

```
var cssDev = [{
  loader: 'style-loader'
}, {
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
   sourceMap: true
  }
}, {
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: true
  }
}]
```

=

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./~/sass-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./src/scss/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/sketch-arrow-2.png' in 'C:\www\webpack\src\scss'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./~/sass-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./src/scss/style.scss 6:77832-77870
 @ ./src/scss/style.scss
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/app.js
```

How could I make the terminal output exactly the file that contains the style?